# Tridion 2011 SP1 - Access denied during publishing DCP

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, publishing

Tridion 2011 SP1 - Access denied during publishing DCP.

We are getting access denied error during committing deployment. After reviewing the permissions, we found the DCP is getting published to the `Data` folder path that is specified in the cd storage config but it is not writing the DCP XML under (publication folder) example: `e:\tridion\data\dcp_1234_34564.xml`, but it should create under (`e:\tridion\data\pub36\dcp_1234_34564`).

When we saw the logs on DEBUG mode, we see it says the file processed from `c:\windows\temp` to `e:\tridion\data\dcp_1234_34564.xml`

We are running the content delivery service and broker service.

Please let us know if we are missing anything.

Comment: I think it will be useful if you add some additional information, like an exctract of your storage configuration and a bit of the logfile showing the error. You can **edit** your question and add these.

Comment: is your page publishing working?